# Package update gone wrong (React Native project)

Tags: css, react-native, render, package.json, google-fonts

After my last coding session with my mentor, he suggested I run

```
yarn upgrade-interactive [--latest]
```

and go through packages to update.

The app was compiling in the emulator but not fully - no icons, and the font (Caveat, a google font) was not loading. Further, there were issues with RN picker select.

I began upgrading packages based on the color-coding system (red first).

This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "rituals",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/caveat": "^0.2.3",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.14.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.21.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.15.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "chalk": "^5.3.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "expo": "~49.0.21",
    "expo-constants": "^14.4.2",
    "expo-device": "^5.6.0",
    "expo-font": "~11.6.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.5.0",
    "expo-linking": "^6.0.0",
    "expo-notifications": "^0.23.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.2.3",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-tab-view": "3.5.2",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.6",
    "react-native-web": "^0.19.10",
    "react-native-webview": "13.6.3",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3",
    "react-uuid": "^2.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.16.0",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "prettier": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I'm at the same place as before: the app compiles (without loading icons or the Caveat font, however) and any interaction results in the following: render error :9:34: Unknown word

I'm on a branch - what is recommended at this point? I need to go back and undo some of the package uprgrades, but I'm not sure how best to proceed.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using npm

```
npm update
```

Using yarn

```
yarn upgrade
```